# Can I get a Green Card through my sister if I have no official records to show that she is my sister?

Tags: usa, greencard

I have a US citizen sister, my father's daughter. However, we do not share a last name and there is no indication on any offical records that she is my father's daughter. My father has already passed away, but we (my sister and I) have a close relationship.

I'm interested in knowing if there is any possibility for me to acquire a green card through her sponsorship. Can I "prove" that she is my sister through DNA testing or somehow else get a green card based on our close family relationship?

Comment: Was a government birth certificate issued at your birth? Can you obtain a copy? Was a birth certificate issued at your sister's birth? Can you obtain a copy? Birth certificates usually state the parents' names, so your father's name should appear on both.

Comment: So this is your half-sister (different mothers)? Was she born in wedlock (her biological parents were married to each other when she was born) or out of wedlock? If the latter, did her parents ever marry after she was born? Did your father support her?